# get the filesize of a preexistant pdf with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

There is a possibility to get the size of a given file during the translation process and show this in resultant xml?

I don't think to have any chance, but I try and cross the finger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure XSLT/XPath I am not aware of a way to read out the size of a file (in bytes?), with extensions like http://expath.org/spec/file#pr.size it should be possible, if supported or integrable into your XSLT processor.